# como alterar um objeto ao invés de uma propriedades de cada vez usando JPA

Tags: jpa-2.0

Tenho uma `@Entity` chamada Funcionário, quando preciso alterar as propriedades nome, cargo, salario etc.. tenho que fazer uma propriedade de cada vez conforme exemplo abaixo.

**Minha classe FuncionarioController**

```
@Transactional
public void atualizar(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) throws NegocioException {
    if (funcionarioModel.getCargo().isEmpty()) {
        throw new NegocioException("Não é possível fazer a Alteração campo cargo está vazio !");
    }
    this.funcionarioRepository.porId(funcionarioModel.getCodigo()).setCargo(funcionarioModel.getCargo());
}
```

Minha classe repositório recebe o `id` que veio da minha classe `FuncionarioController`. O método `find()` da classe repositório conforme abaixo encontra o objeto e faz a alteração na propriedade especifica no caso cargo.

```
public FuncionarioModel porId(Long id) {
    return manager.find(FuncionarioModel.class, id);
}
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível ao invés de alterar uma propriedade por vez, fazer a alteração no objeto, evitando assim um código grande. Como estou fazendo hoje, tenho que escrever todas as propriedades novamente.

```
Não Recebi nenhum retorno mais a resposta era simples, resolvi conforme abaixo.

**classe repositório**
public void alterar(FuncionarioModel funcionario) {
         this.manager.merge(funcionario);
    }

**classe Controle**
@Transactional
    public void atualizar(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) throws NegocioException {
        if (funcionarioModel.getCargo().isEmpty()) {
            throw new NegocioException("Não é possível fazer a Alteração campo cargo está vazio !");
        }
        this.funcionarioRepository.alterar(funcionarioModel);
    }
```

Comment: O que seria alterar o objeto todo? O que você precisa alterar nele ?

Comment: Douglas Obrigado pelo retorno, acho que consegui resolver conforme postado acima, porem vou recolocar a pergunta , quem sabe você não tenha uma melhor solução.... Bom tenho um objeto chamado Funcionário e preciso fazer alterações na seguintes propriedades nome, cago, salario e gostaria de fazer isso de uma só vez somente setando o objeto ou seja Funcionário ao Invés de setar uma propriedade por vez Nome Cargo Salario...